# Android Dependencies problem - Teleop & camera tutorial

Tags: ros, rosjava, android, dependencies

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

I followed this doc [rosjava_core](http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/rosjava_core/html/index.html) and [android_core](http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/android_core/html/index.html) to install a fresh android_core rosjava_core on my fresh ubuntu 11.10. After gradlew instructions, I imported projects into eclipse.
PubSub tutorial works properly but I still have difficulties to get android_tutorial_teleop and android_tutorial_camera tutorial to work.

Teleop app failed on the runtime due to a ClassNotFoundException : org.ros.android.views.visualization.VisualizationView

Camera app throws a ClassNotFoundException caused by org.ros.android.views.RosCameraPreviewView

These classes are declared in the android_gingerbread project, which is set in the "Android Dependencies" of Teleop and Camera projects. According to this [android doc](http://tools.android.com/recent/dealingwithdependenciesinandroidprojects) "android dependencies" are automatically exported that's why I'm confused now.

I probably missed something because pubsub tuto works correctly and required org.ros.android.views.RosTextView from android_gingerbread.

Thanks for help,
Jérôme

PS : Got the same exceptions when running the apk generated by gradlew

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33025/android-dependencies-problem---teleop-&-camera-tutorial/) by [Jérôme Monceaux](https://answers.ros.org/users/2283/j%C3%A9r%C3%B4me-monceaux/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-04-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jérôme Monceaux](https://answers.ros.org/users/2283/j%C3%A9r%C3%B4me-monceaux/) on 2012-05-06**:
Please, note that teleop depends directly on android_honeycomb_mr2, but android_honeycomb_mr2 depends on android_gingerbread, so teleop depends on android_gingerbread too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If I'm right, teleop is depending on honeycomb, not on gingerbread.
Thats what is said in the build.gradle of the project.

---

Originally posted by [Kat](https://answers.ros.org/users/1982/kat/) with karma: 155 on 2012-05-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0